# What are antonym-like prefixes to the Greek "crypto"?

Tags: prefixes, latin, greek

What is a prefix that is similar to "public", or "accessible", or "ubiquitous" such that it is harmonious with the spirit of currency needing to be of public domain, widely adopted, accessible, etc.

It doesn't have to be of Greek origin, perhaps Latin.

Comment: Greek antonymic prefixes might include *apocalypto-* (from a verb meaning "reveal") or *phenomeno-* (from a participle meaning "shown"), but don't count on their currency in English, or even in Greek for that matter.

Comment: In addition to 'secret', a possible translation of crypto- might be 'hidden'. Given that, it occurred to me to suggest 'gymno-', which means naked or exposed.

Comment: What about _pan-_ for "ubiquitous"?

Comment: Could you give examples of how you would use this? It seems to me that you don't need any prefix at all, because the unprefixed word would be interpreted as open by default.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking about crytpocurrencies such as Bitcoin. They are by nature difficult to access, which arguably decreases the value of the commerce it drives. So I thought, well what would be the anti-cryptocurrency?

Comment: That makes my point: _currency_ is the anti-cryptocurrency. You need the prefix to change the normal meaning.

Comment: Not a prefix, but if you're scouring dead languages you might think of tweaking the well-known *lingua franca* (a means of communication open to all) to give you something like *libra franca* (but I'm no classicist, so this suggestion should be treated with great caution).

Comment: @Barmar Cryptocurrencies are still currencies, just like salt water fish are still fish. "Fresh water fish" is a useful term to call out non-salt water fish. It's a useful question, even if there may not yet be a generally accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Phanæro-, meaning "apparent".

The Cryptozoic (hidden life) was followed by the Phanærozoic (obvious life). Also cf phanærogam (visible seeds) and cryptogam (spores).

Comment: Hi, Jonathan, welcome to EL&U. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential parts? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score -1):

These are all inexact antonyms but maybe they'll help:

- co-
- exo-
- hyper-
- omni-
- over-
- pan-
- per-
- peri-
- super-
- ultra-

Comment: With, over, around, everywhere, above, throughout - these are close to the opposite of hidden or exclusive or inaccessible. Why the nay-saying to these prefixes?